# Swift compiler recursive code optimisations (similar to Haskell)

Tags: swift, haskell, recursion, functional-programming, compiler-optimization

Does the Swift compiler use fusion to optimise code?

Let's say we want to write code to calculate the sum of the square roots of all positive numbers in a list. In Haskell you can write

```
sumOfSquareRoots xs = sum (allSquareRoots (filterPositives xs))
  where
    allSquareRoots []     = []
    allSquareRoots (x:xs) = sqrt x : allSquareRoots xs

    filterPositives [] 
      = []
    filterPositives (x:xs)
      | x > 0     = x : filterPositives xs
      | otherwise = filterPositives xs
```

This code is quite easy to read (the first line is very neat - almost English; the parts after the `where` are local.) This style also makes use of powerful built-in functions such as `sum` and we could make the other functions public and have them reused. So, good style.

However, we might be concerned that it is less efficient than having a one-pass function. (It pass through the list first to filterPositives then to get allSquareRoots of this and finally to sum this up.) Due to Haskell's, so-called, *lazy evaluation* execution strategy, however, the overhead is significantly less than in most other languages. Moreover, a good Haskell compiler can usually derive the one traversal version from the more elegant multiple traversal version using a process called *fusion*.

My question - does the Swift compiler deploy such optimisation strategies when compiling recursive functions?

Comment: I highly doubt it - much of the optimization that haskell is able to do is based on its "lack" of side-effects. Swift has side effects, it has variables, it has state, etc.

Comment: Replace `filterPositives` with a function that also increases a global counter and change `allSquareRoots` to compute something that depends on such global counter. In this case it's not possible a single traversal version. So: it **cannot** in the general case, and *probably doesn't* even when those functions are simple pure functions.

Comment: Maybe Swift has some "generator objects"/"streams"/.., which can produce a value one-at-a-time, so that you can get a single pass if you code using these generators. It will not be as optimized as with fusion, but at least it's single pass.